# Weird issue using split command in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to split the string given below into name value pairs and further store & display it in the same order was as it is displayed.

```
$tagpair="8=FIX4.2 9=204 35=8 58=90: Unknown Option 10=118";
```

I was attempting to do this with the split command but I was struggling the moment I encountered a string with empty spaces (I need to keep them).

Comment: Do you have this in a loop?

Comment: Your problem is you're probably splitting on spaces to get your tagpair (to break down to key/val pairs).  `90:` has a psace after it so the next value is `Unknown` and then `Option`, which doesn't have an `=` delimiter;

Comment: Just use [`my %hash = split /=|\s+(?=\S*=)/, $tagpair`](http://ideone.com/IPzybD)

Comment: provide the output as well. So user can understand how the string should be split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you're looking more for something like:

```
my $tagpair     = "8=FIX4.2 9=204 35=8 58=90: Unknown Option 10=118";
my $rev         = reverse $tagpair;
my $keyvalpairs = [ grep {$_=reverse $_} reverse @{[ split(/(?:=[^\s]+)\K\s/, $rev) ]} ];
my $keyval      = {};                 #unnecessary but used to display output

foreach my $pair (@$keyvalpairs){
   my ($key,$val) = split/\=/, $pair;
   $keyval->{$key} = $val;            #unnecessary but used to display output
}
```

---

#### Output of the hashref

Note: you'd want to use an array or a Tie::IxHash object if the order of your key/val pairs are important.

```
print Dumper($keyval);
$VAR1 = {
          '35' => '8',
          '8' => 'FIX4.2',
          '10' => '118',
          '9' => '204',
          '58' => '90: Unknown Option'
        };
```

---

#### Explanation

- I reversed the tagpair string to get around the variable-width lookbehind, that you would otherwise need to split on only *the space before* the *key*
- I used `\K` in the RegEx to keep the *equal sign* and *key* and only split on the whitespace -- if you look up the meaning of `\K` the docs say it keeps everything to the left of it (the whitespace is to the right because we reversed the string)
- There are several ways you could loop through to get the proper keyvalpairs, in this case I used `grep` as a looping mechanism. *Right or wrong*, it loops through array of results.  Remember the results were generated on a reversed string, so the array generated is in reversed order, but so are the generated strings (you might want to dump to have a better understanding, since that wording can be confusing). Anyhow, to get the key/val pairs in the proper order, we have to re-reverse the array we created (this is what's passed into `grep`), remember the string in those array elements are also reversed, so we have to undo that (that's the reverse inside the `grep`)
- Once you have your array of key/val pair strings, you need to break those down into their respective variables, which is done using a `foreach` loop (splitting on the `=`)
- You could write cleaner and more descriptive code by not doing the `grep` and instead using another `foreach` loop, but this was to give you something new to look at. *the power of Perl scripting*

Comment: vol7ron : Thanks much for your response, this does answer what I want to do, I just need to get my head around the grep statement.  Further, I need to maintain the order how I parse the values in as I will need to print it out in the same exact order elsewhere, any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: I tried to say this in my note.  Use an array of an array.  In the for loop you could `push @somearray, [$key,$val];` and loop through them later with $somearray[0][0] being your first key and $somearray[0][1] being your first value.  The other thing to look into is Tie::Hash (or Tie::IxHash) http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.20.0/lib/Tie/Hash.pm  to maintain the key/val pair ordering of associative array/hashes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for helping me out here, my apologies to everybody for not being clear the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to actually capture an array, not two scalar variables. I could not repeat your problem when I made that fix:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $tagpair = "8=FIX4.2 9=204 35=8 58=90: Unknown Option 10=118";
my @values = split(/=/, $tagpair);
print Dumper \@values;
```

Here's what I get:

```
$ ./test60.pl
$VAR1 = [
          '8',
          'FIX4.2 9',
          '204 35',
          '8 58',
          '90: Unknown Option 10',
          '118'
        ];
```